# Reduce amount of data in hibernate while still making use of hibernate features

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

assume I have a database like this: (not the actual db but enough to illustrate the issue)

[image: Database]

The Complete and total fields are just a counter of the isComplete and the total Task records per condition (per tasklist or per project). They are repeated (database de-normalization?) for easier fetching since at each stage I want to include a counter of progress.

I have the entities like this:

```
// other fields, getter and setters omitted for brevity

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_info")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String userName;
    
    @Column(name = "image")
    private String imageUrl;
    
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "project_user",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="user_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="project_id"))
    private Set<Project> projects;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "creator_id")
    private User creator;
    
    @Column(name = "image")
    private String imageUrl;
    
    @Column(name = "creation_date")
    private Date createdAt;
    
    @Column(name = "total")
    private int total;
    
    @Column(name = "complete")
    private int complete;
    
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "project_user",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="project_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="user_id"))
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"projects", "connected", "notifications"})
    private Set<User> members;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    private Set<TaskList> taskLists;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "task_list")
public class TaskList {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name = "image")
    private String imageUrl;
    
    @Column(name = "creation_date")
    private Date createdAt;
    
    @Column(name = "complete")
    private int complete;
    
    @Column(name = "total")
    private int total;
    
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "task_list_id")
    private Set<Task> tasks;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "task")
public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
    
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "task_images", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="task_id"))
    @Column(name = "image")
    private Set<String> imageUrls;
    
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "task_id")
    private Set<TaskMember> handledBy;
    
    @Transient
    private Set<Note> notes;
    
    @Column(name = "complete")
    private boolean complete;
    
    @Column(name = "creation_date")
    private Date createdAt;
    
    @Column(name = "completion_date")
    private Date completeDate;
    
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "task_handler")
public class TaskMember {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
    private User user;
    
    @Column(name = "assignmentType")
    private String assignmentType; //maybe change to enum?
}
```

The issue is after adding some json ignore properties (to resolve cyclic serialization issue), i get a json like this:

```
user: {
//fields
projects: [{
             //fields
             tasklist: [{
                         //fields
                         tasks: [{
                                 //fields
                                }]
                       }]
          }]
}
```

which is not only a huge response (containing pretty much all the data) but also takes a lot of space on the server.
What I would instead like to have is this:

```
request to sign in:

user: {
//fields
}

request to endpoint1 with parameter user id

projects: [{
// fields
}]

request to endpoint2 with parameter project id
tasklist: [{
// fields
}]

request to endpoint3 with parameter tasklist id
tasks: [{
// fields
}]
```

this will make it easier to update the client for any changes while having the api as stateless as possible (i dont want any data in the server memory aside from session and security stuff).

I know that one way is to drop entities and do it pure sql style, but that means I lose hibernate features such as cascading and data integrity.

what are my options here? If there is a mistake in the entity relationships or database design please enlighten me.
Thanks in advance :)

Edit: I am not using any custom serializer class, just base jackson. Annotating properties with @jsonIgnoreProperty prevents serialization of unwanted fields but i dont think it prevents fetching them in the first place (could be wrong here).

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public List<User> getAllData() {
        // just runs a basic "from User" query
        List<User> users = userService.findAll();
        return users;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you want to show user his tasks, right? So don't fetch `Project`s, and instead go through `TaskHandler` and all that stuff.

Comment: Well, it shouldn't be too hard to provide queries/repository methods to just fetch the data needed for your endpoints. What problem are you facing?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov no, what I want is to show the user his projects. Then when he clicks a project, to show the tasklist. Clicking a taskList shows the tasks. (i know how to handle clicking and requests)

Comment: @Thomas In this setup, once i fetch a user. all the data is fetched with it due to jackson serializing it for the api. I want to keep them related (for cascading and transaction purposes) but i dont want all the data to be together. I want to be able to select each part distinctly using a different endpoint. This way i can control things like limits and offsets.

Comment: @Movsac, so then what's the specific problem? Define fetches as lazy, and make sure serializer doesn't pull on them. It'd be simpler if you showed an example of serializing code as well.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov i am not using any custom serializing tricks. All I'm using is the controller prefixed with Restcontroller (updated the post). Doesn't ignoring them with the JsonIgnore annotation still have them fetched?

Comment: That might be the problem: you're directly exposing your internal model (entities) to the outside world (REST clients). What you might want to do instead is build another model, e.g. using data transfer objects that just represent the data needed for that endpoint (move data using a mapping library such as mapstruct) or by providing custom serialization/deserialization (one way to do that with Jackson might be mixins - provide mixins with different annotations for each endpoint).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I had misunderstood how hibernate works. After learning more about it and toying with it. I believe I finally understand. It turns out, even if it is related, it doesn't fetch the data unless it is asked for.

One option is to use the jsonignore on the hidden properties to prevent jackson from accessing the getter (which in turn would not fetch the object), but this means I can't customize it later on.

A better approach is to use a DTO.

Thanks @Thomas for your comments